# Does the collocation "to have a bad sleep" exist?

Tags: grammar, word-choice, collocation

Does the collocation "to have a bad sleep" exist? For example, will it be grammaticaly correct if I use it in the sentence "He had a bad sleep last night and was not able to wake up on time"?

Comment: I would not use the phrase in this context because I understand it to mean "did not sleep well" and so waking would not be a problem. Perhaps "he slept **heavily** and was not able to wake up on time."

Answer (score 2):

No, the normal way to say this is "He slept badly last night." I have never heard the construction "to have a bad sleep", and I don't think a native speaker would ever use it.

**Edited to add:** user121863's answer has convinced me that this construction is now being used by (presumably) native speakers. I am surprised, but I must accept the evidence.

Comment: But note that the *opposite* situation can be idiomatically described as *He had a good [night's] sleep,* as well as *He slept well.*

Comment: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have+a+bad+sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20bad%20sleep%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Yes, @HotLicks. That is part of the evidence that I am referring to, already linked in user121863's answer.

Comment: The question was closed on an apparent general reference issue...

Answer (score 1):

Though not a common collocation, to have a bad sleep, (on the calque of “have a good sleep“) appears to show increasing  usage instances from the ‘90s, at least according to [Google Books](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=have%20a%20bad%20sleep&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Chave%20a%20bad%20sleep%3B%2Cc0).
The more common expression, though, is “to sleep badly”.

See some usage examples [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22have%20a%20bad%20sleep%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:2019,cd_max:2019&lr=lang_en)

Comment: You made me edit my answer!

Comment: @TonyK - well, if “a good sleep” works, why should a bad one not.